# How to get the cookie from Frontend + Next.js

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, cookies

I am using Next.js 14 in my Frontend and hosted my Node.js Express to AWS ec2 instance. I got SSl certificate for my Node.js application.

I am able to see cookie in Chrome DevTools > Application > Cookies.

**Issue**: When i try to access those cookie from Frontend by `document.cookie` i get an empty string, even though it is there in Cookies section

her is the code from node.js:

```
res.cookie('accessToken', accessTokenJWT, {
    secure: true,
    signed: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneDay),
    sameSite: 'none'
  })

  res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshTokenJWT, {
    secure: true,
    signed: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneWeek),
    sameSite: 'none'
  })
```

I have tried to set `httpOnly:false` Still no success.

Can someone assist me?

p.s. I tried the solutions from this site, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i resolved this issue by hosting both BE and FE on aws ec2 instance. After deployment both applications, i was able to get the cookie